# UITextView not updating frame unless two or more characters are typed on new line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I noticed a strange behaviour with UITextView.

I logged it's height in `textViewDidChange`, and found that it's height stays the same unless there are two or more characters on a new line. This is giving me some serious issues. Anyone knows a fix?

Using `[textView sizeThatFits:textView.frame.size]` returns the correct size as soon as a new line is created.

I am using autolayout and my `UITextView` is embedded in a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: why don't you add two spaces in the last of your textview. It will resolve your issue immediately.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. Can you show me an example?

Comment: are you using autolayout ?? make sure you did set any constant height constraint

Answer (score -1):

You should pass max height in place of **textView.frame.size** like:

```
[textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)]
```